# jQuery's :checked not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to disable a text field if a checkbox isn't selected however its not working as it should.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GV7U9/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" checked /><br />
#<input type="text" size="8" maxlength="6" id="colour" placeholder="ffffff" />

<script>
    $('#check').change(function(){
        if( $('#check:checked') ){
            $('#colour').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#colour').attr('disabled','');
        }
    });
</script>
```

That is a short example of what I'm trying to do but it doesn't want to work. There are no errors in the console.

Could someone please explain why this isn't working?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use .prop() also use the checked state to set the value

```
$('#check').change(function () {
    $('#colour').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/S5HnW/)

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, this one was the only that worked in my actual code even though all the others worked in jsfiddle. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 8):

try `$('#check').is(':checked')`

here's [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GV7U9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `length` to find if element is checked otherwise your condition will be `true` always. When the length is greater then 0 condition will be `true` and `false` otherwise.

```
 if( $('#check:checked').length ){
        $('#colour').removeAttr('disabled');
  } else {
        $('#colour').attr('disabled','');
  }
```

You can use checked property directly without condtion.

```
$('#check').change(function () {
    $('#colour').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#check').change(function(){
    if($('#check').is(':checked')){
        $('#colour').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#colour').attr('disabled','');
    }
}).change();
```

In order to make your jsFiddle working, you need to:

1) Include jQuery library

2) Use `is(':checked')` to check whether checkbox is checked or not.

3) Trigger `change()` event on page load to catch the default checked status.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GV7U9/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

use `this.checked`

```
$('#check').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
            $('#colour').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#colour').attr('disabled',true);
        }
});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/5G5rZ/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/4dwkG/

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" checked /><br />
#<input type="text" size="8" maxlength="6" id="colour" placeholder="ffffff" />

<script>
    $('#check').change(function(){
        if( $('#check').is(":checked") ){
            $('#colour').removeAttr('disabled');
        } else {
            $('#colour').attr('disabled','');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

check this code..using this.checked

```
 $('#check').change(function(){

                if(this.checked)
                $('#colour').removeAttr('disabled');
                else 
                $('#colour').attr('disabled','disabled');

        });
```